# Amcharts V4 how to fix the value of CategoryAxis?

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/bubble-based-heat-map/

I'm trying to build this Bubble-based heat map, the x-y Axis here are all category type.

There are three types of data:

```
    {
        "hour": "1am",
        "weekday": "Sun",
        "value":
    }
```

And the value is added by SQL on the backend:

```
  chart.data = <?=$json_data?>;
```

But they are not in the exact order, and not all day have the value. For example, when the data started with Thursday 8:00, the chart will start with Thursday 8:00. And since there's no value on Sunday at 0:00, can not sort from the data side.

So, Is it possible for Amchart to fix the weekday from Sun-Sat, and hour from 0:00 to 23:00 on the javascript side?

Thank you so much for your help.